# Characterization of compositon of rotations

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, rotations, orthogonal-matrices

It's more of an open-ended question about rotations, and I am not sure how to formulate it.

Let's say we are in a n-dimensional space (n can be large, like 20) and we compose simple rotations within that space. By simple I mean that each is in a single <strike>hyperplane</strike> 2D plane. The planes may not be orthogonal, but they all go through the origin.

Is there a simple way to characterize the rotations? Maybe re-decompose along the axes? Maybe this article applies?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group#Canonical_form

Comment: Usually a "hyperplane" of an n dimensional space, means an n-1 dimensional linear space, but I don't think that's what you want here.

Comment: Are you familiar with the group of orthogonal matrices with determinant $1$? (SO($n$))

Comment: @Ted Sorry, I meant 2D plane, but I didn't know the right term. I modified the text

Comment: @Noah

I am not familiar with it. Is this the Wikipedia link or do you have a better reference that I can read?

Comment: Start with the orthogonal group which includes the reflections and then specialize the the rotations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group

Comment: @TonyBruguier I'm not really sure what you mean by rotations which each occupy a $2D$ plane, so maybe this isn't helpful, but if what your after are the rotations in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which fix a one dimensional subspace (the axis of rotation) the special orthogonal group (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group) is what you're after